# Can I water indoor fruit trees with aquarium water?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care, manure, green-manure

I have kiwi, lemon, orange, mandarin and avocado trees, grown from seed from normal fruit which I have eaten. 
I also have an aquarium with turtle. I've treated aquarium water with ReptoSafe and ReptoFresh.

I was thinking to use the water from the aquarium (containing turtle manure) to water my trees. They are just small indoor trees.

1. Is it feasible to use aquarium water on my trees?
2. What water parameters I should measure (like pH)?
3. How should I measure those parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aquarium water from freshwater animals is excellent for plants. If you are interested in taking this to a new level, do a search for **Aquaponics**.

Get a pH Testing Kit to determine if the water is too acidic or basic for your plants first. You can likely buy one at the same store where you buy your ReptoSafe and ReptoFresh.

You will want a pH of around 6 for your trees. You can adjust the pH level of your water as needed with additives designed for adjusting the pH level of aquarium water. Ideally, the pH level of your aquarium's water will be acceptable without additives. You can then just filter out any solid waste and pour directly onto your plants.

Answer (score 3):

Aquarium water can be used to water the plant.  The water contains rich nutrients for plant growth.

Be careful if you have been using medication in the aquarium water.  The medication can affect the plant.

Besides, do not raise any plant on aquarium water alone.  Fresh water should be the primary means of watering.  You can add aquarium water once or twice a week.

References

http://lifehacker.com/5867013/use-dirty-aquarium-water-to-fertilize-plants

http://www.petsnhobbies.com/2015/04/aquarium-waste-water-as-fertilizer-for.html

Comment: What is your definition of 'fresh water'?

Answer (score -1):

Sure why not?  Just less fertilizer you'll have to use for your plants.

Comment: I don not know, but I just do not wanna try and maybe hurt my trees. I can find what pH is OK for my trees and see if water its ok. As I asked, do I have to measure something else (pH)? Thanks.